# adding columns to a table from second table with different data sizes (pyspark.sql)

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am pretty new to programming and pyspark.sql.
I understand basic joining functions for two tables based on a common column but I struggle to join two tables when different number of rows.

I need to select specific columns from each of the tables below (different column name) and created a combined/merged table.
I tryin to explain my case with an example below:

My identifier column between two tables (table 1 and 2) is part_ID=Part No.   The naming is different but they are the same and I can use either column name in the final table or defined a new one (i.e. ID_No). Some of the columns from Table 1 and 2 are not needed in final merged_table.

Table 1   (Table 1 can have several entries for each part_ID)

| Part_ID | area_code | Work_risk | part_Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1_0 | Low | 100 |
| 1 | a1_1 | Medium | 200 |
| 1 | a1_2 | High | 300 |
| 2 | a2 | Medium | 200 |
| 3 | a3 | High | 300 |

Table 2   (Table 2 entries for each part_no is unique and each part has only one entry.)

| Part_No | Part_Description | Supply_Risk | Supplier_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Green | No Potential Risk | S1 |
| 2 | Blue | Potential Risk | S2 |
| 3 | Red | Potential Risk | S3 |

Desired outcome:
The merged_table should look like something below:

| ID_No | area_code | Work_risk | Part_Description | Supply_Risk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1_0 | Low | Green | No Potential Risk |
| 1 | a1_1 | Medium | Green | No Potential Risk |
| 1 | a1_2 | High | Green | No Potential Risk |
| 2 | a2 | Medium | Blue | Potential Risk |
| 3 | a3 | High | Red | Potential Risk |

I appreciate any help/guidance on how I should code this with pyspark.sql!

Thanks!

Your Friendly Programming Newbie! :)

Desired outcome is Merged table described above.

Comment: It's a basic `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the full outer join, to do this you need to union a left join with a right join, like this:

```
SELECT columns
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.CommonColumn = table2.CommonColumn
UNION
SELECT columns
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2
ON table1.CommonColumn = table2.CommonColumn;
```

Note that you can use `UNION ALL` if you want to return all duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

```
data1 = [
    (1, 'a1_0', 'Low', 100),
    (1, 'a1_1', 'Medium', 200),
    (1, 'a1_2', 'High', 300),
    (2, 'a2', 'Medium', 200),
    (3, 'a3', 'High', 300)
]
columns1 = ['Part_ID', 'area_code', 'Work_risk', 'part_Cost']
table1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, columns1)

data2 = [
    (1, 'Green', 'No Potential Risk', 'S1'),
    (2, 'Blue', 'Potential Risk', 'S2'),
    (3, 'Red', 'Potential Risk', 'S3')
]
columns2 = ['Part_No', 'Part_Description', 'Supply_Risk', 'Supplier_number']
table2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, columns2)

merged_table = table1.join(table2, table1.Part_ID == table2.Part_No, 'inner')

merged_table = merged_table.select(
    table1.Part_ID.alias('ID_No'),
    table1.area_code,
    table1.Work_risk,
    table2.Part_Description,
    table2.Supply_Risk
)

merged_table.show()
```